# Why does @Array.clear not work

Tags: ruby

I'm doing the about_dice_project.rb in ruby koans. I defined the class DiceSet with the roll method as follows:

```
 class DiceSet
   attr_reader :values

   def initialize
      @values = []
      @old_values = []
   end

   def roll(num_dice)
       @old_values = @values

       while @values == @old_values do
           @values = []

           (1..num_dice).each do
               rnd = 1 + rand(6) 
               @values << rnd
           end
       end
    end
 end
```

I replaced

```
@values = []
```

with

```
@values.clear
```

and it doesn't work; the ruby terminal just freezes. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank You!

Comment: Kindly comment as to why the question was downvoted, so I can correct any mistakes.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you but to improve your question I'd replace "wacky" with an actual description of your code's behaviour and how it differed from your expectation

Comment: Saying something "doesn't work" is a red flag for a lot of people. Try and be more descriptive than that. Saying "won't run to completion" is significantly better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `@old_values = @values`, both variables point to the exactly same object. Now, when you assign a new array to `@values` as in `@values = []`, `@values` now is a different array object.

However when running `@values.clear`, you are changing the existing array, i.e. the same `@old_values` still points to. In this case, when adding new entries to `@values`, you are adding them to `@old_values` too (as they both point to the same object).

You should read a bit more about how Ruby handles variables and objects. This is part of the first lessons of about all Ruby tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Is @values defined earlier?  If it's not defined before it is referenced in the *@values = []* line, you will end up with an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `clear' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not familiar with about_dice_project.rb, but I'm not sure what the purpose of @old_values is as defined in this function.  Also, if you define *@values = []* at the beginning and do *@old_values = @values*, you will end up with an endless loop... which may also be what is going "wacky" :)